# Comparing two instances of a struct

Tags: c, struct

I have my own data type since C89 doesn't allow bool type. I can't use C99 sadly.

I have tested the below code and my program is not even recognizing that the names are different. The names are working just fine. I have those loaded in an instance of the struct.

```
struct ROOM roomList [MAX_ROOMS_COUNT];
```

I used memset and strcpy to copy in a list of rooms from a room array. Testing this gives me the results I want like so...

```
printf("%s", roomList[1].name)
printf("%s", roomList[2].name)
...
printf("%s", roomList[7].name)
```

The rooms array has 7 values.

```
#define MAX_ROOMS_COUNT 7

typedef enum {
  true = 1, 
  false = 0
} boolean;

struct ROOM {
  char name[8];
  char* type;
  int numConnections; 
  char* connections [MAX_CONNECTIONS_COUNT];
};

boolean isSameRoom(struct ROOM x, struct ROOM y) {
  //printf("Is Same Room, 1:%s, 2:%s\n", x.name, y.name);

  if (x.name == y.name) {
    //printf("ROOM IS SAME!"); 
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;         
  }
}

struct ROOM getRandomRoom() {
  int random = rand() % MAX_ROOMS_COUNT;
  return roomList[random]; 
}

void addRandomConnection() {     

  struct ROOM A;
  struct ROOM B;

  A = getRandomRoom();

  do {
    B = getRandomRoom(); 
  }while(isSameRoom(A, B) == true);

  //printf("Add Random Connection, 1:%s, 2:%s\n", A.name, B.name);   //for testing purposes

}
```

Using the print statements I can see that the isSameRoom function isn't working. It's generating random rooms just fine, but there are instances when I run the program that I'm getting the same room for A and B. Any idea why? Thanks! :)

Comment: You cannot compare strings with `==`, you have to use `strcmp`

Comment: Thanks! I wondered if that was what it was.

Comment: Aside: you say you output the room names with `roomList[1].name` thru `roomList[7].name` for `#define MAX_ROOMS_COUNT 7` rooms. In C arrays are indexed from `0` so that should be `roomList[0].name` thru `roomList[6].name`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using pass-by-value for these structures, which is pretty inefficient.  You should do pass by reference.

Second, as others mentioned, you cannot compare fixed-size strings with `==` in C; you have to use [`strncmp`](http://mdoc.su/o/strcmp) or some other structure.

Perhaps a better idea would be to do the whole comparison of the whole structure with [`memcmp`](http://mdoc.su/o/memcmp)?

```
return memcmp(&A, &B, sizeof(struct ROOM)) == 0;
```

Comment: *If* there is padding between struct members, is `memcmp()` uncertain? For an initialised `struct` I guess **no** because uninitialised parts are zeroed, but for a `struct` where members' values are individually assigned? For an unpadded `struct`, in the case where the only difference might be a string with unused space in the array, could they compare different when they are actually the same?  Moreover, if any member is a *pointer* to a data value, the data might be the same, but the pointer different. I propose that the only safe way is to compare each member, according to its type.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Obviously, this would only work for a shallow comparions (re: pointer), but good point about the string. And I see that you already mentioned that. woops! Comment deleted.